# C# WPF-How to make the borderless window's content follow to resize when the window is resizing

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf borderless window, I had an close button (image) and a tab control. I can resize the window by setting the window property ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip", but the window's content (image button and tab control) did not. So, how can I overcome this problem? Here's my code:

```
<Window x:Name="Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window" Height="240" Width="330" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="{x:Null}" 
        Foreground="{x:Null}" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="CloseBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Width="19" Margin="303,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="CloseBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown" ToolTip="Close">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/closeButton.png"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/closeHoverButton.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="Title" Content="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,0,0,0" Width="200"
                   Height="22" Padding="3" VerticalAlignment="Top""/>
            <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Width="310" Margin="8,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                        FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="11">
                <TabItem Header="Header Title" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="11">                    
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Post  your  current XAML, a screenshot of the problem, and a proper explanation of the desired output.

Comment: Why you using margins and heights.. if everything you giving as constant why resize will work. Use grid and place controls in it. Grid rowdefination or column defination should have 1*, 2* like that. so automatically it will align the controls in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not following the WPF layouting way of laying out the position of the controls, they will remain fixed as per your margings.

You should read about layouting in this link : http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

And choose a layouting strategy to your liking.

My guess is that you have just dragged these elements on your form using the designer. The designer is using margins all the time when you do it like that and actually pushing you in the wrong direction.

Whenever I drag an element on my form, first thing I do is to remove the margins. But I also create a sketch of my forms before I begin. To have an idea how many rows and columns I need, or which combination of layouting i am gonna use. Because yes, you can combine several strategies together.

Comment: Hi @Philip Stuyck, thanks for your explanation, I used Grid Panel to overcome my problem and everything works fine now.